# Add a column that divides another column into n chunks, R

Tags: r, split

There's no easy way to describe my question, that's probably why I was not able to find answer through search.

So I have a data frame with 3 columns, one of the columns is Subject number, the other two columns are Correctness and Block. There are 2 participants, each was exposed to 2 blocks of 3 stimuli in each block.

```
     subj corr block
1     1    1     1
2     1    0     1
3     1    1     1
4     1    1     2
5     1    1     2
6     1    1     2
7     2    0     1
8     2    1     1
9     2    1     1
10    2    0     2
11    2    1     2
12    2    1     2
```

So what I want to do is to create another column that look at a specific subj number and divide the block columns corresponding to the subj into 3 even chunks (the original df has 2 chunks). In general, I want to know how to divide the stimuli each subj is exposed to in to N chunks and input the chunk number into another column.

```
    subj corr block newblock
1     1    1     1        1
2     1    0     1        1
3     1    1     1        2
4     1    1     2        2
5     1    1     2        3
6     1    1     2        3
7     2    0     1        1
8     2    1     1        1
9     2    1     1        2
10    2    0     2        2
11    2    1     2        3
12    2    1     2        3
```

Comment: Really?. I gave up after seeing to over 50,000 lines and the display was still not complete. Read [MCVE] and reflect on why we might see this as not "M". And questions with no attempt at coding are generally met with resistance to do your entire project for you. SO is not a coding service. We expect you to write code that would download and than make some effort.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
n_chunks = 3
df %>% 
  group_by(subj) %>% 
  mutate(newblock = rep(1:n_chunks, each = ceiling(n() / n_chunks))[1:n()])
```

How much of this is necessary depends on your use case. If you can guarantee that `n_chunks` evenly divides the number of observations for each subject you can simplify to:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(subj) %>% 
  mutate(newblock = rep(1:n_chunks, each = n() / n_chunks))
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregor! There was a missing bracket in the first code block before [1:n()], but otherwise it solved my problem perfectly well.

df %>% 
  group_by(subj) %>% 
  mutate(newblock = rep(1:n_chunks, each = ceiling(n() / n_chunks))[1:n()])

Comment: If anyone else run into the Error 'This function should not be called directly', detach dplyr first with detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE), then load plyr first, then load dplyr